# Master the dual screen in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, 14.10

My setup is a laptop connected to an external screen I have just bought, so that I have now a built-in 14" display (1920*1080) and an extra 24" display at 1920*1200. Because the widths match I use both displays, one on top of the other.

I intend to be more productive with the extra space, but it turns out it is not so easy to begin with. I would like to know a few tips to get started.

First I'm thinking of how to have Ubuntu remember where I like my windows to be. Let's take evince for instance: I open a lot of pdf files in a day, and some of them open in the external screen, some of them open in the laptop built-in screen.

I don't think the answer should be version-specific, but who knows ? So my version of Ubuntu is 14.10.

Comment: re  your flag: you need to keep editing your question to add more details - what you have tried/what questions you've researched but doesnt work. You dont have any details about your ubuntu version.  Focus on single questions - there are at least two questions here that can be separate questions. Look at this meta for more details: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11876/if-a-question-i-wrote-has-no-replies-can-i-edit-it-in-order-to-move-it-up-on-th